# Wireshark doesnt capture local traffic ... why?

Tags: wireshark, capture

I have windows 10 x64bit and in VMware i have Kali 2018.1 version . i have Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter in my computer. When i open Wireshark from Win10 i can capture to only packets of Vmware ip and other computers which are at localhost cant capture . i searched all internet but i couldnt find an answer .. When i open Wireshark from VMWare it doesnt capture http ports on windows 10 and other computers at the localhost.VMware network adapter : VMNET0 (bridged ) and edit -->virtual network editor VMNET0(vmnet information Qualcomm Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter )internet works but doesnt capture packets .. I scanned network there are other ip's expect mine .. but it doesnt capture any packets expect of my computer. I thought maybe i must change my ethernet card.I bought a card i download the rtl8192su-master driver i unzip on the Desktop but i couldnt load drivers how can i load them ? (realtek ) INCA IUWA - 300 N so where i do something wrong ? what is the problem with wireshark??

Thanks ...

Comment: Your English is very hard to understand. Please structure your question. What exactly do you mean by “other computers which are at localhost”? What are you trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: there are 5 computers at wifi ..
i only can capture my win10 and my VMware at the same computer same ethernet card.
Other computers i can not capture.. The problem is why i cant capture other computers?

Comment: well windows has issues with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847168/wireshark-localhost-traffic-capture    and https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback    I've always had to use a program called rawcap(mentioned at the second link),  to do it and then load the result into wireshark

Comment: here's another answer https://ask.wireshark.org/question/189/localhost-capturing/

Comment: ok i download rawcap but 0. 169.2......208 Ethernet Ethernet 1. 169.2.....59 Ethernet 2 Ethernet 2. 169.......5 Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 1 Wireless80211 3. 169.2...... Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 11 Wireless80211 4. 192.168.2.47 Wi-Fi Wireless80211 5. 169.254..... Bluetooth Ağ Bağlantısı Ethernet 6. 127.0.0.1 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 Loopback
Select interface to sniff [default '0']: 4 i select 4 ) wifi connection it starts to capture but this time my localip : 192.168.2.47 and my vmware ip is 192.168.2.174 at the same computer and on the localhost there are ips "192.168.2.212 ; 192.168.2.213" when i s

Comment: It looks like you've created two accounts. Please see [this help center article](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge them, then you will be able to edit your question and post comments on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/731745)

Comment: Stop moving to new devices and/or clearing your browser history and [register](https://superuser.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fsuperuser.com%2f) an account. Using unregistered accounts limits your ability to effectively manage your question and is only usable when your device properly supports browser cookies. It only works on the same browser on the same device. Once you have created a registered account you can request that it be merged with the account used to ask this question via the [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page.